# Time detective duty

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, calculation-puzzle

Consider that you have a beautiful wife (husband). But your after-marriage life is not so beautiful. Your wife (husband) has performed a first adultery act **5** years after a marriage with you and later you have followed with a first adultery act **12** years after a marriage with your spouse.

**Question: How much years separates those two first adultery events ?**

> Hint 1: Assume that after a marriage wife and husband has *separate* and *perpendicular* time axis
>
> Hint 2: Answer has something related to geometry

Hint 3: Graphical representation :

[image]

Comment: This is not [tag:logical-deduction] (read the tag description). I don’t know what it *is* but it feels underdefined, like the answer will end up being speculation based on what little is here to go on. You may need to flesh this out a bit better to have it fit within our guidelines here.

Comment: @Rubio I've changed tags, agree it's not strictly deduction, rather calculation. Hint is the essence of puzzle. I don't know what to add next to not reveal too much. Besides it's more interesting now to see who will come to what solutions, when definition is not very strict.

Comment: Actually, we have close reasons for puzzles so loosely defined that there is no way to demonstrate the correctness of any specific answer. That’s not “more interesting”, it’s just a poorly defined puzzle.

Comment: The problem is that you can find a valid solution for every value you assign to the years, just shift those marriages around. So you should add constraints to limit this value to one specific using more clues.

Comment: @Bananenkopp I've changed hint to be more useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a bad feeling that the answer you’re after is

> 13 years.

Because

> Treating 5 years and 12 years, respectively, as offsets on two perpendicular axes, gives two points that are a straight line distance of 13 years apart (by $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$).

This, of course,

> disregards entirely how time works; I’m not sure what real-world sense this thought approach or answer makes. But it’s the only way I can think of that uses the “hints” (which are decidedly not hints, but rather a vital piece of the puzzle, if indeed my answer is on point).

Comment: My fault of loose definition, seems that clear puzzles can be created only by those who knows english language super-well. I had in mind one marriage event and only two persons involved.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas The problem does not seem to be an issue with English.  You are trying to impose a metaphysics of time that is completely at odds with anything based on reality.  There is no puzzle here: this is purely guessing the intent of a hint, because there is no independent basis for arriving at the answer.

Comment: @ErickWong You don't know a physical reality of time unless you are a physicist, and still even a physicist don't knows it well, take for example first moments of big bang - nobody knows what and which process were active at that time. Or take a look at [Plank time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) at quantum mechanics - time spans even smaller than that doesn't make any sense in a physical system. There's a lot mysteries about time. And, no - it's a valid puzzle, by definition puzzle can be constructed in any way. This puzzle tries to break your usual time definition

Comment: General idea of separate time scales of objects is not new in physics - check [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) [Hafele–Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment) which validated relativity conclusions about different time flow in objects with different acceleration and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but...

> 7 Years.

Reason:

> 12 - 5 = 7

Comment: Read a hint carefully - your solution assumes global time scale :-)